# Where does the clickevent in Enterprise Architect end up?

Tags: c#, event-handling, add-in, enterprise-architect

I am working on an add-in for [*Enterprise Architect*](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/developers/autint.html) in **C#** that involves tabs. Tabs as in, what there is on the bottom of the screen just as in an excel sheet. For example, if you as a user would click on one of the tabs in excel the view will change to this newly clicked tab.

[image: The focus is on the tab with the name "webinterface"]

In the above picture, the tab "web interface" is currently selected. Now what happens in the code when the user clicks on one of the other tabs. Lets say the user clicks on "Program on user PC".

My question addresses anyone who has any *Enterprise Architect* Add-In developing experience. I would like to **catch** the **mouseclick event** that is fired as soon as the user clicks on one of the tabs such that I can respond properly on this event and prepare the view for the user.

I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EA does not make raw Windows input events (keyboard, mouse) available to Add-Ins, but the Context Item event `EA_OnTabChanged()` tells you when the user switches tabs. This sounds like what you're after.

The event includes the name of the tab being switched to, so you just need to match that to know if the event is for you.

Comment: This seems exactly what I am looking for. Do you know where and how I need to override and or catch this event?

Comment: In your Add-In's main class, create a method with the specified name and parameters, and EA will call it when appropriate. See help Automation and Scripting -- Enterprise Architect Add-In Model -- Add-In Tasks

Comment: I implemented it just like you explained. But something weird is going on, it is being called twice. Do you know why this is?